# VBA If Last Two Characters equals "XX" Then Delete Entire Row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to run a macro where it looks at a string and determines whether the last two characters equal "XX", then it is to delete the entire row.

I am getting a object error oh the highlighted below.

```
Sub Oval2_Click()


Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For i = Last To 1 Step -1

`If (Right(Cells(i, "E"), 2).Value) = "TZ" Then`

    Cells(i, "E").EntireRow.Delete

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `.Value` from `Right(Cells(i, "E"), 2).Value`. It's complaining because `.Value` doesn't exist on the **function** `Right`

Answer (score 4):

Though you already have your answer but I wouldn't recommend looping to achieve this. Looping will be slow if you have large number of rows. Here is an alternative which is comparatively very fast. I have also commented the code so that you will not have a problem understanding it...

**Logic**:

1. Use Autofilter to Filter data which ends in "XX"
2. Delete filtered data

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the respective sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Get last row of Col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Use autofilter to identify the cells which end in "XX"
        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*XX"
            '~~> Offset to exclude the header and delete them
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: This code is much better written than the other answers. While the others may work, this is the only answer that follows the best practices for VBA.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
If (Right(Cells(i, "E"), 2).Value) = "TZ" Then
```

Should probably be

```
If Right(Cells(i, "E").Value, 2) = "TZ" Then
```

This should work too:

```
If Right(Cells(i, "E"), 2) = "TZ" Then
```

Comment: Oops... I should have refreshed my page before typing the same response.

Answer (score 0):

I tested. This works and it is the fastest because I also use `Range` to speed up the code.

```
Sub Oval2_Click()

    Dim Rng As Range 
    Dim i As Integer, counter As Integer
    'Please Set Your Range
    Set Rng = Range("E2:E300000")
    i = 1
    For counter =1 To Rng.Rows.Count
    
    If (Right(Rng.Cells(i),2)) = "XX" Then
        Rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else 
       i = i + 1
    End If

    Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: This can't be correct: if you have two subsequent rows, containing "XX", the second one will not be deleted.

Comment: Don't quite understand, but my code generated the expected result. All E entire rows which E Cells contain "XX" are deleted

Comment: Indeed: because there no two subsequent rows, containing "XX". If there were, then the second case would not be deleted.

Comment: okay. What is your suggesion? because I don't know how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I would recommend you to turn the loop around (in the inverse direction):

```
For counter = To Rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
  If (Right(Rng.Cells(counter),2)) = "XX" Then
      Rng.Cells(counter).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next counter
```